# How to create 2 sites in apache/httpd

Tags: linux, apache, webserver

Currently apache is listening on port 80 and documents are in /var/www/html.

I need it to listen on 8000 and by default to have a document directory in /var/www/data

What definitions do I need in the conf file to achieve this? I tried stripping httpd.conf and creating httpd2.conf but I couldnt get it to work, it would point port 80 to port 8000 document directory.

Besides the following, do I need anything else?

Listen 8000

DocumentRoot "/var/www/data"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port and DocumentRoot should be sufficient.

You need to restart Apache after making changes to httpd.conf. You possibly forgot to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use VirtualHost directive:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

For example:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/data1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/data2
</VirtualHost>
```